# Angular : Unable to access passed values in included form

Tags: angularjs

I am passing values from the parent form to included tag/form in angular. However, included form is only able to access a few of the passed values (and not all of them). Below is an example:

**parent-form.html**

```
<form name="siteForm"> 
    <label class="control-label"> Primary Site </label>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="vm.data.primarySite" required>
        <option ng-if="vm.data.parentSite == 'A'" ng-repeat="d in vm.siteOptions.SiteA | orderBy:'toString()'" value="{{d}}" ng-selected="vm.data.site==d">{{d}}</option>
        <option ng-if="vm.data.parentSite == 'B'" ng-repeat="d in vm.siteOptions.SiteB | orderBy:'toString()'" value="{{d}}" ng-selected="vm.data.site==d">{{d}}</option>
    </select>

    <label class="control-label"> Backup Site </label>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="vm.data.backupSite" required>
        <option ng-if="vm.data.primarySite == 'A'" ng-repeat="d in vm.siteOptions.PrimarySiteA | orderBy:'toString()'" value="{{d}}" ng-selected="vm.data.site==d">{{d}}</option>
        <option ng-if="vm.data.primarySite == 'B'" ng-repeat="d in vm.siteOptions.PrimarySiteB | orderBy:'toString()'" value="{{d}}" ng-selected="vm.data.site==d">{{d}}</option>
    </select>

    <site-update-request primary-site="vm.data.primarySite" backup-site="vm.data.backupSite"></site-update-request>
</form>
```

**site-update-request.html**

```
<ng-form name="setupForm">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="setupForm.$invalid || !vm.hasValidFields()" ng-click="vm.submitRequest()">Submit</button>
</ng-form>
```

**controller code**

```
submitRequest() {
    this.request.primarySite = this.primarySite;
    this.request.backupSite = this.backupSite;
    
    submit(this.request);
}
```

**bindings**

```
/*jslint node: true */
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    templateUrl : 'app/partials/site-update-request.html',
    transclude : true,
    controller : 'siteUpdateRequestController',
    controllerAs : 'vm',
    bindings : {
        parentSite : '<',
        primarySite : '<',
        backupSite : '<'
    }
};
```

In the above code, `this.primarySite` is always `undefined` regardless of what's selected whereas `this.backupSite` always has got the selected value. I have tried changing the name of the element but that hasn't worked either. Is there anything I am missing here (being a newbie angular developer)?

Comment: Can we see the code for your `site-update-request` directive? It sounds like your isolate scope linking isn't setup properly. There are a few other concerns that may apply as well, I don't see what value that directive provides. If you need shared validation behavior, that is better encapsulated by a service instead of building the indirection required from a componentized submit button.

Comment: @MarkClark updated the bindings

Comment: "bindings" snippet does not look like a proper directive. also `bindings` is not a valid directive property. The documentation around isolate scopes and their syntax can be found here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-

Comment: Sorry, I have very limited angular knowledge. Could you please provide an example of correct directive? Also, not sure why it's only impacting one property and not all.

Comment: @MarkClark if bindings is incorrect, I expect all the bindings to fail and not just one. Is there anything specific that is not quite right for `primarySite` attribute?

Comment: If you haven't declared an isolate scope, everything from the parent scope will be available. Do you have variables of the same name in your controller scope? If you don't explicitly declare them they will get created if you assign a value to them even in the template.